# run a java file within another java file and display its output to console

Tags: java, console

i have a **hello world** class hworld.class which displays "Hello World" on the console. i am trying to run it from another class in console using the code

```
 public class ftest2  
 {  
    public static void main(String[] arg)  
    {  
     System.out.println("NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED");
      try {  
            Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac hworld.java");  
            pro1.waitFor();  
            Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java hworld");  
            pro2.waitFor();  
         } catch (Exception e) {    
               System.out.println("Some Error");   
               e.printStackTrace();     
                }  
    }  }
```

but when the file is executed, the output of Hello World is not displayed on the console.
the program just starts and displays

```
  NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED
```

insted of

```
  NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED    
  HELLO WORLD
```

how it would be possible to display the output of HELLO WORLD as well.
(it is example program. i want to display the output of a program within another program)

if there is another way to call a class within another class to display its output. then please mention it.

Comment: yes you can say. both the class files ftest2 and hworld give output to console. i am calling a class within another class to display its output

Comment: Tip: Don't put empty catch block like this catch (Exception e) {    } ever, ever. It will mask all of your exceptions.

Comment: @PradeepSimha it is just an example

Comment: @adeeliqbal, just a small suggestion :)

Comment: A poor example.  Pradeep is right.  If an exception is thrown, your second Process will never be run - and you won't know it.

Comment: i have added the catch block but still the issue is unresolved. i have also updated the question

Comment: You're assuming that your hworld code compiles correctly and the .class file is written to some place where the class loader can find it.

Comment: And I request you to follow some java code standards

Comment: @duffymo yes ofcourse it is working. if i declare an object of hworld class and call it. the output is displayed correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read in the `InputStream` of the process, which is

> The stream obtains data piped from the standard output stream of the
>   process represented by this Process object.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()

Read `InputStream` and write out to `System.out`:

```
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    int b = -1;
    while ( (b =  inputStream.read()) != -1 ) {
        System.out.write(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the inputstream of your process to System.out, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    System.out.println("NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED");
    try {
        Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac hworld.java");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro1.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: it uses the try with resources syntax of Java 7 but is easily transposable to Java 6- if necessary.

Comment: +1 This answer is to know whats happening when compilation, if any errors, will be printed in console.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are getting exception and you've not printed it.

```
public class ftest2  
 {  
    public static void main(String[] arg)  
    {  
     System.out.println("NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED");
      try {  
            Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac hworld.java");  
            pro1.waitFor();  
            Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java hworld");  
            pro2.waitFor();  
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some Error");
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }  
    }  
}
```

and another way

```
public static void main(String[] arg)  
{  
     System.out.println("NEW FILE PRINT LINE EXECUTED");
     hworld.main(arg); // since main is a static method can be called w/o instance
}
```

Comment: no there is no error displayed if i have added the catch block